# Is RMI based cache invalidation still valid for DD4T 2.0 or only JMS based can be used

Tags: cache-channel-service, dd4t-2

We have implemented Tridion Object Cache into our application which is a DD4T 2.0 based application. I have set up cache channel service and publisher accordingly so that the cache can be invalidated in case an item is published.
In the cd_cache log of my application I can see that the cache is being invalidated for the items which I am publishing but the component or page is not getting refreshed and is showing the old content.

```
2017-01-05 12:03:03,533 DEBUG CacheChannel - Received event from another VM [CacheEvent eventType=Invalidate regionPath=/com.tridion.storage.publication key=2031]2017-01-05 12:03:03,533 DEBUG CacheChannel - Received event from another VM [CacheEvent eventType=Invalidate regionPath=/com.tridion.storage.publication key=2031]
```

This is only happening when I am having a large value of DD4T.CacheSettings.Page or DD4T.CacheSettings.Component in my config file if i decrease them to 1 sec, the content is getting refreshed.
I am just wondering if these setting are required in DD4T 2.0 as this version totally depend on Tridion object cache and not on the call back mechanism.

Can someone please confirm if RMI based invalidation can still be used in DD4T 2.0 or can we use only JMS based invalidation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no invalidation of the DD4T cache in DD4T .NET 2 out of the box.

However, DD4T Java has cache invalidation out of the box.

The Cache Channel Service will invalidate the [Tridion Object Cache](https://sdltridionworld.com/articles/whatisthesdltridionobjectcache.aspx) but not DD4T's cache. You will need to rely on TTL or [integrate with ActiveMQ/JMS](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/16339/43).

Comment: Cache invalidation for DD4T Java 2.0 is OOTB..

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Rob's answer, in DD4T version 2, the framework does not support RMI.

This does not mean you cannot use RMI for invalidation of the Tridion Object Cache in case you have that turned on in the web application and are using the in process Tridion libraries. If you use RMI for this part however, the DD4T stack cannot listen to invalidation messages - there only JMS is supported.