# DD4T 2.0 Dynamic Component cache not getting invalidated

Tags: 2013, dd4t-2, object-cache

We have implemented Tridion object cache invalidation using the approach mentioned [here.](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/16338/dd4t-2-0-cache-not-getting-invaliated) The cache invalidation is working fine if we are changing anything in static Component or Page. But in case if we change and publish any dynamic Component, it is not getting reflected on the Page.

Is there any way someone has implemented cache invalidation using Apache MQ with DD4T where it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this blog link might help you to implement DD4T 2.0 .NET web apps with ActiveMQ caching invalidation.

- [How to Setup SDL Web 8 Deployer and DD4T 2.0 .NET Web app with ActiveMQ Caching Invalidation](https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/tridion-developer/b/feed/posts/how-to-setup-sdl-web-8-deployer-and-dd4t-2-0-net-web-app-with-activemq-caching-invalidation)

**Note:**

In order to work with Tridion 2013sp1 deployer, need to rebuild this **dd4t-cachechannel** source against 2013sp1 deployer jars, rest of the configurations are same for both 2013sp1 and web 8.5

**dd4t-cachechannel.jar** - You can download it here https://github.com/dd4t/dd4t-cachechannel/blob/release/release-1.0/dist/dd4t-cachechannel-1.0.jar

I hope it helps.