# DD4T 2.0 Dynamic Components Cache Invalidation is not working

Tags: web8.5, dd4t-2, cache

We have implemented cache invalidation using the approach mentioned [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/16338/dd4t-2-0-cache-not-getting-invalidated/16339#16339).
The cache invalidation is working fine only for the static components or pages.

But in case of dynamic component (like promotion or similar articles), are not getting reflected on the page. May I need to configure or implemented something special for dynamic component presentation?

For information I am using SDL Web 8.5 along with apache mq and DD4T 2.0.

I found a similar question in [Trex](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/16648/dd4t-2-0-dynamic-component-cache-not-getting-invalidated), but looking for some answer. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this following blog links might help you to fix.

- [Upgrading to SDL Web 8.5 can break your DD4T JMS decaching](https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/tridion-developer/b/feed/posts/upgrading-to-sdl-web-8-5-can-break-your-dd4t-jms-decaching)
- [How to Setup SDL Web 8 Deployer and DD4T 2.0 .NET Web app with ActiveMQ Caching Invalidation](https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/tridion-developer/b/feed/posts/how-to-setup-sdl-web-8-deployer-and-dd4t-2-0-net-web-app-with-activemq-caching-invalidation)

**Note:**

The JMS messages were changed and the TCM URI is now prefixed with '1:', In SDL WEB 8.5 version CacheEventTypeId included.

For example:

SDL Web 8 sends 17:3565 for pages

SDL Web 8.5 sends **1**:17:3565 for pages

SDL Web 8 sends 17:52916:154 for DCPs

SDL Web 8.5 sends **1**:17:52916:154 for DCPs

I hope it helps.